# In PL/SQL (Oracle), can exceptions propagate across function/procedure calls?

Tags: oracle, function, stored-procedures, exception, plsql

as it happens in enclosed blocks
If an anonymous block calls a function that raises exceptions, those are neither shown on console nor trapped in enclosing blocks...
What's more, after being caught by handler in the function, lines after function call in the anonymous block are executed normally!

The called procedure is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE qt(pno number, qty OUT number)
IS
BEGIN
select sum(qty_on_hand) into qty from products where productno=pno;
END;
```

The calling block is:

```
DECLARE
qty number;
BEGIN
qt(&pno, qty);
dbms_output.put_line('qty is: '||qty);
END;
```

In case of invalid product number, no error is shown; why?

Comment: 'after being caught by handler in the function'... if the exception is being caught then it won't be propagated, unless the catcher re-raises it. It sounds like the catcher *might* be using `dbms_output` to 'report' the error, in which case you'd need to `set serveroutput on` to see it. You really need to show the function and anonymous block code to get any sensible help, otherwise we can only guess what's happening and what you want/expect to happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your specific example, I think that no exception is being raised at all.  You say "in the case of an invalid product number", by which I assume you mean a product number that does not exist.  That sounds like you expect your query to throw NO_DATA_FOUND, but since it is using an aggregate function without a GROUP BY, it will actually return a single row containing `NULL` if there are no matching rows.

Answer (score 8):

If the exception is caught by the handler in the function **and not re-raised** then no exception will be triggered in the caller.  This is correct behaviour.  If you want the exception to be visible to the caller you must re-raise it in the function using the `RAISE` command:

```
FUNCTION fun ...
...
EXCEPTION
  WHEN some_exception THEN
    ...
    RAISE;
END;
```

Alternatively you can raise a different exception e.g.

```
EXCEPTION
  WHEN some_exception THEN
    ...
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'My error message');
END;
```

Comment: @pop stack: I think your question is unclear.  It says "after being caught by handler in the function".  What does that handler actually do - can you show the code?

Comment: Now that we can see your code, Dave Costa's answer is more relevant.  There is no exception being raised.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Tony's answer.
You may not know what type of exception a calling function may throw. In this case you can do:

```
EXCEPTION
  WHEN exception_that_may_occur_in_my_function THEN
    ...
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'My error message');

  WHEN others THEN  -- Any exception that can come from a function I'm calling
    RAISE;

END;
```

Comment: Isn't that redundant? Anything you don't explicitly catch will bubble up to the caller anyway?

Comment: Yes, but it's just to illustrate the principle of "when others" in error handling.